# ng-apimock use global variables in mocks without double quotes

Tags: json, angular

I have added [ng-apimock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-apimock) to our Angular project. We have successfully created first mock definitions and wrote tests with protractor.

Now we want to start using global variables in mock definitions. We already have a mock definition like this:

```
{
  "expression": "MyServiceEndpoint",
  "method": "GET",
  "name": "Edit",
  "isArray": false,
  "responses": {
    "default": {
      "default": true,
      "status": 200,
      "headers": {},
      "data": {
        "id": 3,
        "text": "some text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

From above sample I want to replace property "id" (number) from data with variables. According to the specification from ng-apimock the synthax here is: %%theVariableName%%.

To get a valid JSON I have to add double quotes and it would look like this:

```
"data": {
            "id": "%%theVariableName%%"
            "text": "some text"
        }
```

But then I get a different JSON. Instead of 3

```
"data": {
            "id": 3
            "text": "some text"
        }
```

I get "3"

```
"data": {
            "id": "3"
            "text": "some text"
        }
```

Any ideas how to use variables without double quotes?

Answer (score 1):

All JSON value have to be contained within quotes. Whatever you are consuming the JSON with it should expect `"3"` instead of `3`.